# How to install a specific version of Java 8 using Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Docker Container (using a Dockerfile) with a specific version of Java 8 on it. A lot of the examples target the latest release.

```
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get update -y

RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

I have a need where i want to control the specific version of Java that my container is provisioned. Any hint on how to achieve this? For Example Java 8 update 31.

Comment: As that PPA only contains the most up-to-date package, it is not possible using WebUpd8.

Comment: I've build a Dockerfile where you can specify the version via a Tag, but I will not post it as an answer. If you want to have a look, https://github.com/MartinSeeler/docker-oracle-server-jre#usage-from-docker-hub.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As most PPA packages pack the latest stable version, I would recommend installing Java manually from Oracle, just like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/536161/134964).

You can do all the work in the script too, the steps are:

- get the tarball with `wget`,
- untar it with `tar -xz`,
- use `update-alternatives` to set is as default

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the official Java image from the [Docker Hub Registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/java/)

Admittedly it doesn't offer the Oracle JDK due to licensing restrictions, but it's the simplest way to integrate Java into your Docker workflow.

Answer (score 0):

For Docker Container OS: **Cent 6.6**

Use this command in your Dockerfile to update your JDK version to 1.8:

```
RUN touch /var/lib/rpm/* \ 
 && yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```